# How to enable AJAX for the the 'Add to Cart' button of product widgets in Magento 2.2.3?

Tags: magento2.2.3

In Magento 2 the normal Add to Cart button has a very nice AJAX-based logic to add products to the cart.
However, when we use a Catalog Products List widget for example in CMS pages in the **Home Page** the button in this products list works with an HTTP POST which reloads the current page.
**I want to add Ajax add to cart in grid.phtml in home page(Widget).**

User experience suffers from this and it would be desirable if the button would have the same AJAX logic like in the default category product lists or on product pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to override new_grid.phtml file

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

Now Just Add

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
"[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
"catalogAddToCart": {
"bindSubmit": true
}
}
}
```

And write your Add to Cart button under the form.Just Replace
form

```
<?php 
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()])
?>
<button class="action tocart primary" data-post='<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postData ?>' type="button" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?>">
    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
</button>
```

To

```
<?php
$postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
$postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item), ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]);
$widgetdata = json_decode($postData);
//var_dump($mydata->action);
?>
<form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $_item->getSku() ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $widgetdata->action ?>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $widgetdata->data->product ?>">
   <!--<input type="hidden" name="<? //= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED   ?>" value="<? //= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]   ?>">-->
  <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
  <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="action tocart primary">
      <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank Ashna. this active is on ver 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I Found this free extension from Tigren that adds ajax support to add to cart button in widgets ,
here is the link to it [link to free extension](https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/)

note: if you don't like the popup you can disable it from the admin dashboard

hope this will help someone in need

Answer (score 0):

**here custom solution to add product in cart with custom route code**

Note : whatever data get in param which are must set from your list product addto form.

Your custom PHTML file

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" <?php if ($_item->getOptions()) :?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="is_cart_page_addcrosssale" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="is_configurable" value="<?php echo $product_type; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    
    <?php if($block->getChildBlock("configurable_options")){ ?>
        <?= $block->getChildBlock("configurable_options")->setData('product', $_item)->toHtml(); ?> 
    <?php } ?>

    <?php 
    $productTypeInstance = $this->configable; //Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable
    $productAttributeOptions = $productTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_item);
    if (!empty($productAttributeOptions)) {
        foreach($productAttributeOptions as $productAttributeOption){
            ?>
                <span><?php // echo $productAttributeOption['label']; ?></span>
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $productAttributeOption['attribute_id'] ?>]" data-selector="super_attribute[151]" data-validate="{required:true}" id="attribute151" class="super-attribute-select" aria-required="true">
                    <?php
                    $opt = 1;
                        foreach($productAttributeOption['values'] as $configure_option)
                        {
                            if ($opt == '1') {
                                $_op_selected = 'selected';
                            }else{
                                $_op_selected = '';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <option selected="<?php echo $_op_selected; ?>" value="<?php echo $configure_option['value_index']; ?>"><?php echo $configure_option['label'] ?></option>
                            <?php
                            $opt++;
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                </select>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <button type="submit"
            title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
            class="action tocart primary">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
    </button>                                               
</form>
```

**Controller File :**

```
<?php
/* HSCode snippet
* Ajax product add to cart 
* remove item from cart
*/
namespace Vendor\Namespace\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class AddProducttocart extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    protected $cart;
    
    protected $product;

    
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        Product $product,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

   
    public function execute()
    {

        $content = '';

        try {
            // Ajax add to cart 
            if($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_configurable') == 'simple'){
               $content = $this->addProductToCartSimple();
            }

            if($this->getRequest()->getParam('is_configurable') == 'configurable'){
               $content = $this->addProductToCartConfig();
            }


            // remove item from cart by id 
            if($this->getRequest()->getParam('accessory_remove_id') != '' ){
                $content = $this->removeItemFromCart($this->getRequest()->getParam('accessory_remove_id'));
            }             
           

            
        }catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            
            return $content="false";

        }


        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        // return $resultPage;

        $response = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_RAW);
        $response->setContents($content);
        return $response;
    }


    public function addProductToCartSimple(){
        
        $productid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product', false);

        $productprice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price', false);

        $form_key = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', false);

        $params = array(
            'form_key' => $form_key,
            'product' =>$productid,
            'qty'   =>1,
            'price' =>$productprice
        );


        $product = $this->product->load($productid);

        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);

        $this->cart->save();
        
        $content=$productid;

        return $content;
    }


    public function addProductToCartConfig(){

        $productid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product', false);

        $productprice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price', false);

        $form_key = $this->getRequest()->getParam('form_key', false);
        
        $options = $this->getRequest()->getParam('super_attribute', false);


        $params = array(
            'product' => $productid,
            'super_attribute' => $options,
            'qty' => '1'
        );
        
        $product = $this->product->load($productid);

        $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);

        $this->cart->save();

        $content = $productid;

        return $content;
    }


    public function removeItemFromCart($productId){

       $productInfo = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

       foreach ($productInfo as $item){

            if($productId == $item['product_id']){

                $item_id = $item['item_id'];

                $quote_id = $item['quote_id'];

                $this->cart->removeItem($item_id)->save();

            }
       }

       $content = $productId;

       return $content;
    }
}
```